# IndexedDB's callbacks not being executed inside the 'fetch' event of a Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, indexeddb

I'm trying to do a couple of things in the IndexedDB database inside the 'fetch' event of a service worker, when the aplication asks the server for a new page. Here's what I'm going for:

1. Create a new object store (they need to be created dynamically, according to the data that 'fetch' picks up);
2. Store an element on the store.

Or, if the store already exists:

1. Get an element from the store;
2. Update the element and store it back on the store.

The problem is that the callbacks (onupgradeneeded, onsuccess, etc) never get executed.

I've been trying with the callbacks inside of each other, though I know that may not be the best approach. I've also tried placing an `event.waitUntil()` on 'fetch' but it didn't help.

The 'fetch' event, where the function `registerPageAccess` is called:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {                 
                event.waitUntil(function () {
                    const nextPageURL = new URL(event.request.url);
                    if (event.request.destination == 'document') {
                        if (currentURL) {
                            registerPageAccess(currentURL, nextPageURL);
                        }
                        currentURL = nextPageURL;
                    }
                }());

                /* 
                *    some other operations
                */
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});
```

`registerPageAccess`, the function with the callbacks.
I know it's plenty of code, but just look at `secondRequest.onupgradeneeded` in the 5th line. It is never executed, let alone the following ones.

```js
function registerPageAccess(currentPageURL, nextPageURL) {

    var newVersion = parseInt(db.version) + 1;
    var secondRequest = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, newVersion);
    secondRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {

        db = e.target.result;
        db.createObjectStore(currentPageURL, { keyPath: "pageURL" });
        var transaction = request.result.transaction([currentPageURL], 'readwrite');
        var store = transaction.objectStore(currentPageURL);
        var getRequest = store.get(nextPageURL);
        getRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {

            var obj = getRequest.result;

            if (!obj) {
                // Insert element into the database
                console.debug('ServiceWorker: No matching object in the database');
                const addRes = putInObjectStore(nextPageURL, 1, store);
                addRes.onsuccess = function (event) {

                    console.debug('ServiceWorker: Element was successfully added in the Object Store');

                }
                addRes.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.error('ServiceWorker error adding element to the Object Store: ' + addRes.error);
                }
            }
            else {
                // Updating database element
                const updRes = putInObjectStore(obj.pageURL, obj.nVisits + 1, store);
                updRes.onsuccess = function (event) {

                    console.debug('ServiceWorker: Element was successfully updated in the Object Store');

                }
                updRes.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.error('ServiceWorker error updating element of the Object Store: ' + putRes.error);
                }
            }
        };
    };
    secondRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
        console.log('ServiceWorker: secondRequest onsuccess');
    };
    secondRequest.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error('ServiceWorker: error on the secondRequest.open: ' + secondRequest.error);
    };
}
```

I need a way to perform the operations in `registerPageAccess`, which involve executing a couple of callbacks, but the browser seems to kill the Service Worker before they get to occur.

Comment: Are you waiting for the function call to complete before responding?

Comment: Since the 'fetch' response didn't depend on the function `registerPageAccess`, I just wanted to be fully executed eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All asynchronous logic inside of a service worker needs to be promise-based. Because IndexedDB is callback-based, you're going to find yourself needing to wrap the relevant callbacks in a promise.

I'd strongly recommend *not* attempting to do this on your own, and instead using one of the following libraries, which are well-tested, efficient, and lightweight:

- [`idb-keyval`](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval), if you're okay with a simple key-value store.
- [`idb`](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) if you're need the full IndexedDB API.

I'd also recommend that you consider using the [`async`/`await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description) inside of your service worker's `fetch` handler, as it tends to make promise-based code more readable.

Put together, this would look roughly like:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    // Your IDB cleanup logic here.
    // Basically, anything that can execute separately
    // from response generation.
  })());

  event.respondWith((async () => {
    // Your response generation logic here.
    // Return a Response object at the end of the function.
  })());
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clear and fast answer! I am now using [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) with the structure you recommended, and sadly I'm getting _The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:64228/" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith()_. I think I am returning Response objects everywhere. Maybe I'll have to post another question... Many thanks, @jeff